# x-axis name is outside bokeh figure

Tags: python, bokeh

I have build a barchart in Bokeh but have the problem that the name on the left-most side of the x-axis is outside the figure. My code looks like this:

```
source2 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(district=df2.district,
                                   areaRatio=df2.areaRatio,                                   areaRatioStr=round(df2.areaRatio,0)))

# Figure
p2 = figure(x_range=df2.district,plot_height=300,plot_width=500,
           y_range= ranges.Range1d(start=0,end=1800),
           title="Trees pr. km²")

# Bar chart
p2.vbar(x='district',top='areaRatio',source = df2,width=0.9,color='green')

# remove the grid
p2.xgrid.grid_line_color=None
p2.ygrid.grid_line_color=None
# Make sure bars stat at 0
p2.y_range.start = 0
# Turn the x-labels
p2.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 0.5
# remove - y-axis
p2.yaxis.visible = False
# Remove the toolbar
p2.toolbar_location=None
# Remove the grey box around the plot
p2.outline_line_color = None

# add labels
labels2 = LabelSet(x='district', y='areaRatio', text='areaRatioStr', level='glyph',
                  x_offset=-20, y_offset=0, source=source2, render_mode='canvas',
                  text_font_size="14pt")

# add hover tool
p2.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips = [('Trees pr. km²','@areaRatio{0.0}')]))
p2.add_layout(labels2)
show(p2)
```

In the figure below the left bar is suppose to have the name 'Amager Vest' but at the moment only 'er Vest' is visible.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase border on the left:

```
plot.min_border_left = 15
```